# MATLAB: How to display two images at the same time

Tags: matlab

```
pic1 = double (Pic1);
pic2 = double(Pic2);
pic3 = double(Pic3);
pic4 = double(Pic4);

ILB = 1;
B = pic1./ILB;

ILC = 0.2;
VC(1:1024,1:1024)= 0.581695;
VT = 0.025;
C = (pic2 - B*ILC)./(exp(VC./VT))

IL = 1;
V1 = VT*log((pic3 - B*IL)./(C));
V2 = VT*log((pic4 - B*IL)./(C));

Vapp1(1:1024,1:1024)=0.616185;
Vapp2(1:1024,1:1024)=0.575044;
jp = 0.038;

R =(((Vapp2-V2).*exp(V1./VT))-((Vapp1-V1).*exp(V2./VT)))./(jp.*(exp(V2./VT)-     exp(V1./VT)))
imagesc(R);

j0 = ((Vapp2-V2-Vapp1+V1).*(jp))./(exp(V1./VT).*(Vapp1-V2)-exp(V2./VT).*(Vapp1-V1));
imagesc(j0)
```

I want to display images R and j0 at the same time in separate figures? Is there any error in my coding?

Comment: if your code is not doing what you want it to do, its safe to say it either has an error or is incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `figure;` before this line : `imagesc(j0)`

This will open a new figure window and use the new one for next plot or image! Otherwise the next plot or image will be overplaced on the previous one of the same figure window (which is what your code is doing at the moment)

Comment: While this is correct, you should elaborate a bit more and explain to OP why he has to do that.

Comment: I have another question how to export the data values (i.e. R and j0) shown in the workspace to excel file or to a text file?

Comment: @shoba That's a new question and should be asked separately!